# Ribbon: double clicking so you can add multiple connectors/shapes in sequence

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

In Office 2003 etc, double clicking a toolbar item (eg a connector), put it in an 'auto mode' where you could continue to add connectors one after the other, without going back each time to click the connector icon.

In the ribbon interface I can't see how to do this.  Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the shape you want select "Lock Drawing Mode"